# NPM live server won't load my project website

Tags: javascript, windows, npm, terminal, npm-live-server

I'm new in using NPM. I wanted to load my project website in live server, but whenever I type live-server in the terminal, it only shows LISTING DIRECTORY (which is the list of all the files I have in my project website folder such as html, css, & script) instead of loading my project website. I tried to google it but found no answer. I don't know what to make sure or what to do about it.

Comment: Do you have an index file in your project directory?

Comment: none. What did I miss?

Comment: though the NPM live-server package and the VS Code Live Server extension are different, they are based on some of the same underlying static server technologies / NPM packages, so some of the info from [this answer post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77176224/11107541) applies here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't specify a directory index somewhere (the default is a file named `index.html`) the server doesn't know what file you want to use as an entry point, so it'll just respond with a directory listing.

The [docs](https://github.com/tapio/live-server#usage-from-command-line) say, you can add an index file by specifying the `--entry-file` command line parameter:

> serve this file (server root relative) in place of missing files (useful for single page apps)

Just add the entry point to the startup script, by running

```
$ live-server --entry-point=PATH
```