# Why is VS Code Live Server opening a listing directory instead of my webpage when I Go Live?

Tags: visual-studio-code, liveserver

I am using VS code for react. I have the Live Server extension installed, and whenever I try to go live with VS code it shows me a listing directory with all of my folders and files in the browser instead of running my app. Why does it do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to provide 'index.html' file in exposed directory. It has to be named exactly like this.('index.html')

More info:
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/30234/the-right-way-of-using-index-html

Comment: this is actually not exactly true. there's more nuance that I've provided in my answer post.

Answer (score 7):

Just had this error, you have to open the folder using "open folder". It'll be in the editor panel now. And when you go live it takes you to whatever is in the editor panel.

Answer (score 6):

LiveServer will load the file within the folder in the WORKSPACE assigned to it.

So point to the correct folder and more important, CLOSE active WorkSpaces already opened with LiveServer.

So...
Open the Explorer on VSC and close any open "Workspaces" (save your work)

Target the correct index.html file in a new Workspace.

Once it points to the right file then simply right-click and select "open with LiveServer."

It should work.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a dedicated folder for the file(index.html) to run the code directly in the browser from VS code Live Server.

Answer (score 0):

As a prefacing note, if you're writing your *own* server implementation, or if you webpage requires anything more than just a simple static file server (which is what the Live Server provides), the Live Server extension on its own is either inappropriate, or will not suffice. You should probably instead be writing a [launch configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging) to launch your server, or looking into appropriate ways to launch development servers for your specific server-side technology. Note that if your server is using PHP, .NET, or NodeJS, you may be able to use [ritwickdey/live-server-web-extension](https://github.com/ritwickdey/live-server-web-extension), which is an official extension to the VS Code Live Server extension to support those server technologies.

---

The VS Code Live Serve extension's server-side uses an npm package called [`send`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/send) to attempt to serve files from the local filesystem, and another package called [`serve-index`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-index) to serve a file-explorer interface when you request a path that maps to a directory but the `send` package can't find an `index.html` file in it to serve. You can see the dependencies in [its `package.json` file](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/blob/master/lib/live-server/package.json), and the code for the server-side of the Live Server extension in [its `lib/live-server/index.js` file](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/blob/master/lib/live-server/index.js).

If the editor area of VS Code has UI focus, and the currently focused editor tab is an HTML file, then Live Server will open to that HTML document upon going live. The `files.exclude` setting has no effect on this. The file must be part of the currently opened workspace for this to work.

Live Server doesn't change the default behaviour for [the `index` property](https://github.com/pillarjs/send#index) of its `send` configuration, so if you request a directory containing a file named `index.html`, then that file will be served instead of the directory UI provided by `serve-index`. The `files.exclude` setting has no effect on this.

If there is no file named `index.html` in the directory specified by the `liveServer.settings.root` VS Code setting contributed by the Live Server extension (which has a default value of `"/"`, meaning the currently open VS Code workspace folder), then it will serve the `serve-index`-provided directory UI for that directory. So,

- If you have not touched the `liveServer.settings.root` setting (which has a default value of `"/"`, meaning the currently open VS Code workspace folder), and have purposely put the `index.html` file that you want to be opened upon going live in a subdirectory (Ex. `./foo/bar/baz/`) of your VS Code workspace folder, then you will need to set the `liveServer.settings.root` setting to `"/foo/bar/baz"` in your workspace [.vscode/settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson).
- If the file you want to be opened upon going live is not called `index.html`, you will either need to name it that, or create a symlink with that name to that file.

You can also do more complicated directory mappings using the `liveServer.settings.mount` setting.

If you're interested in looking at some log messages for the server side, at the time of this writing, Live Server's server side prints such messages into the developer console of VS Code, which you can view by opening the VS Code devtools using the `Developer: Toggle Developer Tools` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette). Not sure why it uses that console instead of an [`OutputChannel`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#OutputChannel).