# Why the live server extension is shown the React folders instead of running the code on the browser

Tags: reactjs, npm-live-server

[image describe my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0d7a.png)

Hi Guys, I had this problem when I launched my React project with [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) extension. It showed the project's folders instead of running the application. I've removed Live Server extension and reinstalled it but I've got the same issue. When I run it from the terminal with "npm run start" command it works well, please guide me because I read and test solutions being in this link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55073031/why-is-vs-code-live-server-opening-a-directory-instead-of-running-the-code-in-th) but it doesn't work.

Comment: Click on the build folder and then start the live server. If you haven't built your project. Run `npm run build` first.

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera Thank you for your response, I do what you comment but nothing changed, still shows the directories instead to run the application.

Answer (score 1):

Try your localhost:3000 or npm start

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30793564)

Answer (score 0):

This is because your React code needs to be compiled. You can run a live server using React with

```
npm start
```