# React project Live Server in VScode not opening Chrome, maunually type in end up in listing

Tags: reactjs, liveserver

wired situation. been replicating some React materials. When use live server, one project opens fine chrome, however, another one one not opening at all, if I type in the IP, I always end up with a listing of the project folder.

[This one not applicable to my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55073031/why-is-vs-code-live-server-opening-a-directory-instead-of-running-the-code-in-th)

I also set default browser to Chrome, did that "https" thing.

See my project folder, one thing I notice difference from the workable project, is the missing ".vscode" folder, here I manually addded this one. still not working.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is stupid. Turns out all file or folder names cannot be Chinese language. need to change them names to English language, to all confusing Chinese users.