# NodeJS Express Program Renders Listing Directory Instead of Pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, express, visual-studio-code

I am asking this because all the other answers I have found have not worked or made no sense.  When trying to open one of my .ejs files from my project using Live Server extension in VS Code, my browser renders a "Listing Directory" instead of my pages that I can click through and see my files in my project.  I have tried re-configuring the live server settings and made sure it is using the port specified in my program (3000).  I have my routes set up for an index, login and register page for my user auth system, but cannot get the html to render in any browser I try. I have also uninstalled/reinstalled Live Server.  Any help is appreciated.

My server.js / routes:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.set('view-engine', 'ejs')

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.render('index.ejs', { name: 'User'})
})
app.get('/login', (request, response) => {
    response.render('login.ejs')
})
app.get('/register', (request, response) => {
    response.render('register.ejs')
})

app.listen(3000)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is VS Code Live Server opening a listing directory instead of my webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55073031/why-is-vs-code-live-server-opening-a-listing-directory-instead-of-my-webpage)