# Unable to use Live Server Extenstion with VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, liveserver

I'm coding with VS Code using HTML & CSS & JS.
When I press on "Live Server" button it just don't do anything.

Can you help me?

I already tried:

1. Install VS Code again
2. Install the extenstion "Live Server" again
3. Install Node.js again
4. I Changed port's number in setting.json
5. Check for updates
6. No errors messages
7. I added "liveServer.settings.useBrowserPreview": false in setting.json
8. Change setting: Manage > settings > search "use local" or "live server"> check "use local IP as host".

Comment: do you have an index.html file in the root of your workspace folder?

Comment: No. Should I add one?

Comment: read https://stackoverflow.com/a/77176224/11107541