# How can Live Server in VS Code serve HTML files with other file extensions?

Tags: visual-studio-code, liveserver

In a VS Code project I have HTML files which end in the (proprietary) extension `.HML`. How can [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) in VS Code serve these files as HTML files?

I have seen [starball's answer to "Why is VS Code Live Server opening..."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77176224/65889). It explains how some explicit files without `.html` extension can be served by Live Server, but I am after a solution which can serve *all* `.hml` files the same way as Live Server already saves all `.html` files.

Comment: Thanks @starball. If  I understand your answer to the other question correctly, I need to create symlinks from, say, `mypage.hml` to `mypage.html`, right? But I have _many_ pages in the directory I would like to serve!

Comment: can you not just manually navigate your browser to the URL you want? it serves a directory listing. If you really need something that will auto-serve .htm, then either the live server extension needs to change (either you feature-request or pull-request), or you pick a local dev-server that will actually do what you want.

Comment: @starball, I can navigate to `mypage.hml`, because it is not served with the HTML mime type, the browser just offeres to donload it, not show it as it does with other HTML pages. The server needs to serve it as HTML. So maybe using another server is than the better option...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since mime type header is apparently the issue, I think you're out of luck unless you feel like forking the software or modifying your extension's installation. The Live Server extension uses [the `send` npm package](https://github.com/pillarjs/send) to serve static files. `send` uses [the `mime` npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime), which only maps `html`, `htm`, and `shtml` to the `text/html` mime type.

I haven't tried this, but I think you could technically dig into your `~/.vscode/extensions/ritwickdey.liveserver-<version>//node_modules/mime/types.json` and edit the file to add the extension you want, but you'd need to redo this every time the extension updates.

Even then, it won't be exactly the same as how files with the `.html` extension in their name are served, since `send` special-cases the filename `index.html`. Again, if you want a different behaviour, you'll need to fork or modify your installation.

Comment: Just tried adding my mapping to `mime`'s `types.json`  - and it works. I understand this is only a hack, but it works for me. Thanks for suggesting this. It helps me a lot.